# Explain ますよう + [noun]

Tags: grammar, syntax

Can someone please help me parse the following sentence:

> ...新商品をお試しくださいますようご案内申し上げます。

I guess the meaning is something like "We invite you to try our new product," but I don't understand how ます+よう connects the お試しください with ご案内申し上げます.  I don't even know if I should think of the ます here going with ください or よう (does くださいます occur in other sentence patterns?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation is correct.  The sentence parses thus:

> ...新商品を　お試しくださいます　よう　ご案内申し上げます。

So the ます is not separate at all.  The first verb is in fact お試しくださいます.  The pattern `verb X + よう（に）+ verb Y` means that Y happens for/so that X happens.

> - 彼に電話する**ように**言ってください。　→　Please tell him (**that he should / to**) call me.
> - (Inside train/subway cars as they approach a stop) お忘れものがございません**よう**、ご注意ください。　→　Please make sure **that** you do not forget your belongings (inside the car).

So here, `verb Y` is ご案内申し上げます; it is not a noun as the title indicates.

Since this is from a company to consumers about their new product, they will use super-polite speech.  That is why they use お試しくださいます instead of just お試しくださる or even 試してくださる, and ご案内申し上げます instead of just ご案内します.  Also, leaving out the に after よう is often common in very polite speech, although I can't really explain why other than maybe it just happens a lot.  But the meaning would not change if the に were there.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Just to clarify, does くださいます get used to end sentences, e.g., as in  どうぞお座りくださいます。 Or 書類をくださいます。? I can't remember hearing it used before.

Comment: You can use くださいます to end a statement, but not a request.  So it's perfectly fine to say something like （上司が）書類をくださいます (the boss gives us the documents), but you wouldn't say  どうぞお座りくださいます.  It would just be どうぞお座りください, or if you were being super polite どうぞお座りくださいませ.

Comment: Ah, of course, that makes sense.  くださいます is a polite version of くださる not ください.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Kimball actually, while you're right that くださいます is a  construction from the verb くださる, ください **is** a different construction from the same verb...